# Mockito is not mocking when a service is injected into another service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, mockito

I have a springboot Rest application where one service has to invoke another service method. The reason being when an employee is created in the system, it has to create default role and group for that employee. The flow is REST call to Employee controller-> createEmp service -> this inturn calls createrole service & creategroup service. The functionality works fine. The problem is with Junits. When i try to mock creategroup and createrole calls in createEmp service, actual methods are being called.

```
IEmpGroupService empGroupService;
IEmpRoleService empRoleService;
     createEmp  { 
    //logic goes here
    emprepo.save();
    empgroupservice.createDefaultgroup();
    empRoleservice.createDefaultRole();      
    }
```

Any pointers here please?

Comment: It would help if you posted the jUnits.

Comment: Would it be possible to post your JUNIT code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're writing ***unit tests*** for `createEmp` service, you should not care about what `empgroupservice` and `empRoleservice` do inside them i.e. you should mock them in you junit tests.

You can inject them at class level (using `@Mock`) in you junit class something like this:

```
....

@Mock
empgroupservice mockedEmpgroupservice;

@Mock
empRoleservice mockedEmpRoleservice;

...

public void testCreateEmp(){
    ...
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockedEmpgroupservice).createDefaultgroup();
    Mockito.doNothing().when(empRoleservice).createDefaultRole();
    ...
    // invoke your method under test
    ...
    Mockito.verify(mockedEmpgroupservice).createDefaultgroup(customer);
    Mockito.verify(empRoleservice).createDefaultRole();
}

...
```

Remember to `verify` their invocations as some of the expectations of your test.

PS. I'd also suggest you to follow naming conventions for your class names. For eg. `empGroupService` should be `EmployeeGroupService`.

Comment: Thanks.. Mocking the class is a key.. However, i had to use @Mockbean due to spring boot dependencies..